# Can second rank antisymmetric tensors be constructed from vectors using tensor product?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

My background is in physics. I am motivated to understand tensor behind "a tensor is something that transforms like a tensor." My understanding of a tensor in that a second rank tensor is an elements of $V\otimes V$. I very basic understanding of multilinear maps, but have no understanding of exterior products.

My initial assumption was that if a tensor, T, is an element of $V\otimes V$, there must exist some $\vec{v}, \vec{w} \in V s.t. T=\vec{v} \otimes \vec{w}$. This clearly cannot hold for antisymmetric tensors or a "null" tensor where all the elements are zero. I am not wondering how it is possible to construct an antisymmetric tensor (or, for that matter, other tensors with zero elements) from a set of vectors in V. If so how? (Someone suggested linear combination)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No. They’re linear combinations. Try $v\wedge w = v\otimes w - w\otimes v$.

Comment: @TedShifrin is this the definition of the wedge product on a vector space? (Sorry dumb physicist here)

Comment: Yes, that’s the definition of the wedge product of two vectors; in particular, it is a linear combination, not a simple tensor.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: The answer to the revision of the question is again no. Please learn how elements of $V\otimes V$ look like in components. When $V=\mathbb R^n$ you will find that $V\otimes V$ is the space of *all* $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ matrices. There are many of them that have full rank (as we know) ***but*** the matrix $\vec{v}\otimes\vec{w}$ always has rank at most one.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you that's very helpful. if a set of vectors in V that span V. Take the tensor product of each vector with  itself will the product span $V\otimes V$?

Comment: No. Dimension $n$ becomes $n^2$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you are asking: is every antisymmetric tensor of the form $v \wedge w$?  The answer is no, just as not every tensor in $V \otimes V$ is of the form $v \otimes w$ (when $\dim V \geq 2$).

Example: let $V$ be a $4$-dimensional vector space with basis $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$. In $\Lambda^2(V)$, which is 4-dimensional with
basis $e_i \wedge e_j$ for $i < j$, the sum $\omega := e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4$ does *not* have the form $v \wedge w$ for some $v$ and $w$ in $V$.

To prove that, we describe a property that all $v \wedge w$ have but $\omega$ does not have: under the bilinear mapping $\Lambda^2(V) \times \Lambda^2(V) \to \Lambda^4(V)$ where $(v \wedge w, v' \wedge w') \mapsto v \wedge w \wedge v' \wedge w'$ on pairs of elementary wedge products in $\Lambda^2(V)$, we have $(v \wedge w, v\wedge w) \mapsto v \wedge w \wedge v \wedge w = 0$. However,
$$
(\omega, \omega) \mapsto \omega \wedge \omega = (e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3\wedge e_4) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3\wedge e_4) = 2 e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4,
$$
which is *not* $0$. Therefore $\omega$ is not of the form $v \wedge w$ for some $v$ and $w$ in $V$.

Comment: I wish this was what I was asking. I was actually asking the statement you made in your second sentence. My follow up question would have been the one you answered. Unfortunately, I know almost nothing about the exterior product. However, you seem to be indicating that Ted Shifrin comment on my post doesn't hold? I'm a physics student trying to have a better understanding of tensors than "it's something that transforms like a tensor"

Comment: The statement in my 2nd sentence is about general tensors in $V \otimes V$ (they need not be $v \times w$) but your question is about *antisymmetric* tensors. My second sentence does not address that since it has a broader setting in mind. A problem is that you are asking two *different* questions in the body of your question. If $V$ has dimension $4$ with basis as in my answer, $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_3 \otimes e_4$ is not of the form $v \otimes w$ and $e_1 \otimes e_2 - e_2 \otimes e_1 + e_3 \otimes e_4 - e_4 \otimes e_4$ is antisymmetric without being $v \otimes w - w \otimes v$.

Comment: Yes, this was my confusion. Obviously, you cannot make an antisymmetric tensor with $\vec{v} \otimes \vec{w}$. However, I had thought that they did need be $\vec{v} \otimes \vec{w}$ which you point out they don't which solves my initial question. However, when I preform the tensor product of $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_3 \otimes e_4$ I am unsure how this is a basis as the of V dim(V)=4. The resulting matrix has two nonzero elements. I would think it should span $R^2$ not $R^4$. Also, is the antisymmetric basis you gave a null matrix? I'm assuming standard unit vectors for $e_i$

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "is a basis" (is a member of a basis), what "The resulting matrix" is referring to, or what you mean by asking if an antisymmetric basis is a "null matrix" (is a null matrix a matrix with all entries equal to 0, or do you mean the kernel of some linear map?).  Since you are using terminology in unusual ways, you should indicate what your reference is for this material.

Comment: Fair enough. I appreciate the assistance even if my level wasn't high enough to understand it.